# How to pass data in post request using spread-operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, axios, javascript-objects

here I am trying to send data to the server through Axios API
but the simple technique is working spread-operator not working

```
axios(
  method:'post',
  url:'xxx',
  header:{},
  data:{
    ...data // throw error Bad Request
    name:data.name,
    age:data.age // working fine
  }
)
```

Comment: You could just do `data:data`

Comment: You need commas after each property except the last, including after the `...data` line

Comment: I doubt the last few lines are working fine as it should throw a syntax error.